# Validate email addresses?

Tags: python, email

There is a library I use called `validate_email` which I use to determine if an email address is valid. However, it can only check the domain name.

For example, there is an email address `ppetrov@omirussia.ru` which really exists. If I try to check that that with the code below, it returns `True`.

```
from validate_email import validate_email

email = 'ppetrov@omirussia.ru'
is_valid = validate_email(email, verify=True)
```

However, the email address `petrov@omirussia.ru` *doesn't* exist, and when I try to check that it returns `True` too.

Is any way to check the part of email address before the `@`?

Comment: There's no way to know, other than sending a mail and seeing what happens.

Comment: the number of times i used fake emails and got away with it suggests that checking validity is not doable. That is probably why they introduced the verification emails in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*omirussia.ru* has a `catchall rule`.

That means that the remote email server will answer "Ok" to any email address queried and has been configured this way to avoid email address verification. There is nothing you can do. It is not possible to verify email addresses on servers configured as "CatchAll".

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-all) :

> In the context of e-mail, a catch-all usually refers to a mailbox on a
>   domain that will "catch all" of the emails addressed to the domain
>   that do not exist in the mail server. Configuring a catch-all address
>   can help avoid losing emails due to misspelling. However, many email
>   hosts no longer permit catch-alls since many spammers abuse the
>   feature, spamming random email addresses.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.